# How to do cart limitations?

Tags: android

How to do cart limitations?

1. Number of items for exp 5 items and can't add more
2. Add from only one category

   ```
   btnCart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {
           new Database(getBaseContext()).addToCart(new Order(
                   foodId,
                   currentFood.getName(),
                   numberButton.getNumber(),
                   currentFood.getPrice(),
                   currentFood.getDiscount()
           ));

       }
   });
   btnCart.setCount(new Database(this).getCountCart())
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Inside you onClick method check how many items are in the cart already. Only in case there are less than 5 items, add the new item to the cart.

```
btnCart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

    Database db = new Database(getBaseContext());

    if (db.getCountCart() < 5) {
          db.addToCart(new Order(
              foodId,
              currentFood.getName(),
              numberButton.getNumber(),
              currentFood.getPrice(),
              currentFood.getDiscount()
          ));
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: thank you It works wonderfully, and for add from only one category?